# one_hot_explicit parameter for h2o python raises error

Tags: python, python-3.x, h2o

When training a model in h2o v3.10 using the python h2o library, I am seeing an error when trying to set `one_hot_explicit` as a choice for the [categorical_encoding](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-ueno/2/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html) parameter.

```
encoding = "enum"

gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(
        categorical_encoding = encoding)

gbm.train(x, y,train_h2o_df,test_h2o_df)
```

Works fine and the model uses `enum` categorical_encoding, but when:

```
encoding = "one_hot_explicit"
```

or

```
encoding = "OneHotExplicit"
```

the following error is raised:

```
gbm Model Build progress: | (failed)
....
OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_bde8fcb4777df7e0be1199bf590a47f9 failed with an exception: java.lang.AssertionError
stacktrace: 
java.lang.AssertionError
at hex.ModelBuilder.init(ModelBuilder.java:958)
at hex.tree.SharedTree.init(SharedTree.java:78)
at hex.tree.gbm.GBM.init(GBM.java:57)
at hex.tree.SharedTree$Driver.computeImpl(SharedTree.java:159)
at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:169)
at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1203)
at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Is there some dependency I'm missing or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your encoding choice should work, though you may want to update to the latest stable release of H2O. Here is a code snippet you can run that works, and test if it works for you. If it works then you can try and pinpoint the difference between your previous code and the example below.

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
h2o.init()

# import the airlines dataset:
# This dataset is used to classify whether a flight will be delayed 'YES' or not "NO"
# original data can be found at http://www.transtats.bts.gov/
airlines= h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/airlines/allyears2k_headers.zip")

# convert columns to factors
airlines["Year"]= airlines["Year"].asfactor()
airlines["Month"]= airlines["Month"].asfactor()
airlines["DayOfWeek"] = airlines["DayOfWeek"].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = ["Origin", "Dest", "Year", "DayOfWeek", "Month", "Distance"]
response = "IsDepDelayed"

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid= airlines.split_frame(ratios = [.8], seed = 1234)

# try using the `categorical_encoding` parameter:
encoding = "one_hot_explicit"

# initialize the estimator
airlines_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(categorical_encoding = encoding, seed =1234)

# then train the model
airlines_gbm.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)

# print the auc for the validation set
airlines_gbm.auc(valid=True)
```

Comment: thanks Lauren, I will try the boilerplate code with the test dataset and see if I can whittle down to the difference in my setup. I am currently restricted to using 3.10.x due to reasons outside my control but this is only temporary. Looking forward to trying the AutoML module...